# how to pass data from a component to a service

Tags: angular

I am making a post http call to consume a service .I have to pass one data in the post call but that data is a value which i am giving to a input field.I am able to get the value of that input field in my component but how i can pass that value to my service so that it's available there .
 My service.ts

```
    getValidUser(userId) : Observable<Response>{
let postdata = {
    'isContractor': false,
    "assetNo" : "",
    "assetType" : "",
    "ifAnycustodian" : ""
  }
    let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
return this.http.post('http://localhost:60623/AssetServices.svc/ValidUser/',userId,postdata).map((res:Response) => res.json())
                         //...errors if any
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 no_pad">
  <label class="col-xs-12 no_pad">Primary user</label>
  <form class="col-xs-12 pdngLeft0 example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="col-xs-12 no_pad example-full-width">
      <input matInput #emp
        placeholder="Enter employee no/email ID/AD ID" 
        (change) ="validateuser()"
        (keyup)="onKey(emp.value)"
        name ="empno" [(ngModel)]="empno" class="col-xs-12 no_pad">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>
```

my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
const URL = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';
import{AssetService} from './asset.service';
import {KeysPipe} from './keys.pipe';
import {ObjtoarrPipe} from './objtoarr.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-asset-page',
  templateUrl: './my-asset-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-asset-page.component.css']
})
export class MyAssetPageComponent implements OnInit {
  public empno : string;

  onKey(value: string) { // with type info
    this.empno = value;
    console.log(this.empno);
  }
  constructor(private assetser : AssetService) { }

  validateuser() {
    this.assetser.getValidUser(this.empno).subscribe(res=> {
      this.validuser = res;
      this.isval = JSON.parse(this.isval);
      console.log(this.isval);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
}
```

my service response

```
{"IsUserValidResult":"{\"RequestStatus\":\"SUCCESS\",\"Message\":null,\"Response\":{\"UserId\":\"aj296828\",\"FirstName\":\"Ajay\",\"LastName\":\"Suvarna\",\"Email\":\"ajay.suvarna@xyz.com\",\"FullName\":\"Ajay Suvarna\",\"IsInvalid\":false,\"IsGroup\":false,\"IsContractor\":false,\"Manager\":\"nokhi\",\"EmployeeNo\":1123456,\"SAPStatus\":null,\"EmployeeGroup\":null},\"PageSize\":15,\"UID\":null,\"AdditionalAssetsCount\":0}"}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: the issue is i am not able to pass the input value to the service and because of that i am not getting a successful response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service you the variable your method is accepting is called `emp`, but you are creating and posting a local variable called `empid`. You need to send through the `emp` variable to the API.

Please see below for what should work.

```
getValidUser(emp) : Observable<Response> {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:60623/AssetServices.svc/ValidUser/', emp)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    //...errors if any
    .catch((error:any) =>
      Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}
```

EDIT:

After seeing you need an object sent to your API, please see below:

```
getValidUser(emp) : Observable<Response> {
  let postdata = {
     UserId: emp
     isContractor: false,
     assetNo : "",
     assetType : "",
     ifAnycustodian : ""
  };

  return this.http.post('http://localhost:60623/AssetServices.svc/ValidUser/', postdata)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    //...errors if any
    .catch((error:any) =>
      Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}
```

Comment: This is the error i am getting                                                                                 
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: That is because your API is not returning an object/value. Comment out the `.map().catch` and it should work

Comment: I had to pass some parameters in that post call which i didn't know.I have updated my service code.When i tested my service using rest client it gave me successful response.I passed the following in the input {"userId":"296828","isContractor":"false","assetNo":"","assetType":"","ifAnycustodian":""} and i got a successful response which i have added in the question

Comment: Can you post what your API method expects please?

Comment: i posted just now.It needs five values. Userid(String),IsContractor(boolean), Assetno(string), Assettype(string) and ifanycustodian(string)

Comment: when i am commenting the map and catch i am getting incorrect response then as well                                                                  
  Response {_body: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
↵<!DOCTYPE …onContextSet)</p>
↵    </div>
↵  </body>
↵</html>", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, …}
headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(2), _normalizedNames: Map(2)}
ok
:
false
status
:
400
statusText
:
"Bad Request"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:60623/AssetServices.svc/ValidUser/"

Comment: I've updated my answer again, please note that the items inside `postdata` are case sensitive to the object names in your api.

Comment: No problem, please mark my answer as correct so others can use it if they have similar issues